# Encryption that can use in php as well as unity

Tags: php, android, encryption, unity-game-engine, mcrypt

I have a php application that sends a URL to android application developed in unity. In order to encrypt the url query string, I have used AES encryption using PHP's inbuilt function `mcrypt_encrypt` and now we can not decrypt this in unity. From the php documentation, `mcrypt_encrypt` will deprecate in php 7.

So after researching, I have found that the library `libsodium` do this job neatly. If anyone has done this before in unity and php, am I in the right direction ?

If not, is there any encryption algorithm that can be used in php as well as unity android application ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Encryption algorithms aren't tired to particular programming languages or platforms, the grounds for your question don't really make sense.  Additionally, mcrypt is deprecated and insecure, you should use `openssl_encrypt` instead.

Comment: Thanks. but sorry for my ignorance; if I am using `openssl_encrypt` from php, can I decrypt this in Unity ? Does unity provide libraries for this ?

Comment: If you have access to `System.Security.Cryptography`, then yes.  With due respect, your lack of knowledge about the subject means that you'll likely struggle to implement a solution that is secure.  Remember, just because it works, doesn't mean it is secure.  I'd recommend you just use TLS or similar instead.

Comment: [Why you shouldn't encrypt URL parameters](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/09/comprehensive-guide-url-parameter-encryption-in-php).

Answer (score 1):

Why are you encrypting a URL?  Just use HTTPS.  HTTPS encrypts the entire payload, including the URL.